# Error whilst translating C# to VB.NET

Tags: c#-4.0, vb.net-2010

Can anyone translate the following in VB.NET?

```
// propare a few short names
ChartArea CA = chart1.ChartAreas[0];
Series S1 = chart1.Series[0];

// this would be option one:
S1.IsValueShownAsLabel = true;

// we clear any previous CustomLabels
CA.AxisY.CustomLabels.Clear();
// we create a version of our points collection which sorted  by Y-Values:
List<DataPoint> ptS = S1.Points.OrderBy(x => x.YValues[0]).ToList();

// now, for option three we add the custom labels:
for (int p = 0; p < ptS.Count; p++)
{
    CustomLabel L = new CustomLabel(ptS[p].YValues[0] - 0.5, 
                                    ptS[p].YValues[0] + 0.5,  
                                    ptS[p].YValues[0].ToString("##0.0000"), 
                                    0, LabelMarkStyle.None);
    CA.AxisY.CustomLabels.Add(L);

    // this is option two: tooltips for each point
    ptS[p].ToolTip = ptS[p].YValues[0].ToString("##0.0000");
}
```

This comes from the following Stack Overflow question:
Display Y-Values on Y-Axis without rounding [closed]

I tried the following:

```
area1.AxisY.CustomLabels.Clear()
Dim pointSeries As List(Of DataPoint)

**Line with error:**
pointSeries = mySeriesRecord.Points.OrderBy(Function(x) x.YValues(0))

Dim len As Integer = pointSeries.Count()
For p As Integer = 0 To pointSeries.Count Step 1

    Dim L As CustomLabel
    L = New CustomLabel(pointSeries(p).YValues(0), pointSeries(p).YValues(len) + 0.5, pointSeries(p).YValues(0).ToString("##':'#0.00"), 0, LabelMarkStyle.None)

    area1.AxisY.CustomLabels.Add(L)

Next
```

But that does not work.  The error is:

> OrderedEnumerable
>   2[System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting.DataPoint,System.Double]
>   unable to convert to type System.Collections.Generic.List

Any help would be appreciated.

Robert

Comment: are you missing the .ToList? instead of "pointSeries = mySeriesRecord.Points.OrderBy(Function(x) x.YValues(0))" maybe "pointSeries = mySeriesRecord.Points.OrderBy(Function(x) x.YValues(0)).ToList()"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try something like this?

```
Dim ptS As List(Of DataPoint) = S1.Points.OrderBy(Function(x) x.YValues(0)).ToList()
```

For converting from/to C# to/from VB.NET you can use telerik's online tool:
http://converter.telerik.com/

Comment: Thank you: tolist worked. I put it between the brackets and it should be outside the brackets.